# Avoid duplicated += -= operator code

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

In C++ (and C++11), classes defining a `+` and `+=` operators often define a `-` and `-=` operators that do nearly the same thing (except `+` is replaced with `-` in the function).

What is the best way to avoid duplicated code here (and still achieve good performance)? I am sure there is a good way to do it with functors:

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct num {
  int val;

  const num & operator +=(const num & rhs) {
    return op_equals<std::plus<int> >(rhs);
  }
  const num & operator -=(const num & rhs) {
    return op_equals<std::minus<int> >(rhs);
  }

  template <typename op>
  const num & op_equals(const num & rhs) {
    op operation;
    val = operation(val, rhs.val);
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  num x{1};
  num y{2};
  x += y;

  std::cout << x.val << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this is a simple example; in reality the code in the `+=` and `-=` operators is more complex.

Also, I am not married to functors in the solution-- any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/operators.htm)?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Is replacing duplicated code with more code in total a win?

Comment: @ildjarn As with most C++ questions on SO, I'm sure there's a solution in Boost, but I'm trying to learn better practice. If you know how they work, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: A common pattern is to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`, which minimises repeated code.

Comment: @Oliver: So using Boost is bad practice?

Comment: I think in this particular case, KISS is the best practice.

Comment: @Jon Not necessarily but in general: yes.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm definitely not disparaging Boost! I mean I want to learn how a seasoned programmer would feel about this problem (and not simply use someone elses code). Boost is great though, not insulting Boost!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading-in-c/4421719#4421719

Comment: @Jon No need to be snarky- as I'm sure you know, this is an example. In reality, I'm doing something like addition/subtraction of multivariate sparse vectors. In the past I simply copied code, but would sometimes need to propagate changes 2x. And if that's the best solution, I acquiesce. What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: @Oliver: It is perhaps not *that* obvious that this is an example (vs. a thought experiment). The question was genuine. I applaud your intellectual curiosity, but on the other hand am inclined to believe this is over-engineering things and of doubtful practical benefit.

Comment: If operators `+` and `-` delegate to the `+=` and `-=` you show, is there anything left in them to which you need to _propagate changes_? It seems like you'd have 4, rather than 2 operators delegating to a single template, and any complexity goes in there.

Comment: I think that your code is perfectly fine. It's understandable as to what it does. You may want to check how well you compiler optimizes it -- the construction of the `op` instance may linger and mess things up.

Comment: @KubaOber Can `op` cause problems even if it instantiates no data? I'd assumed it would simply be treated as a global function call underneath...

Comment: The obvious reply: look at the assembly and see if it does in fact look like a global function call :)

Comment: For class types, you'll still have to define operator+ and operator- as two separate functions.

Answer (score 3):

I actually quite like this pattern and use it relatively often. I'm not sure if there is something better than functors for this - if there is, I'm not really aware of it. That being said, with C++11, I'd write this in a slightly different way:

```
struct num {
  int val;

  const num& operator +=(const num & rhs) {
    return op_equals(rhs, std::plus<int>());
  }

  const num& operator -=(const num & rhs) {
    return op_equals(rhs, std::minus<int>());
  }

  template <typename op>
  const num & op_equals(const num & rhs, op&& o) {
    val = o(val, rhs.val);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Note the rvalue reference (which is actually a "universal reference", so can bind to either an lvalue or rvalue reference), and the movement of `op` to a parameter - I don't really like having to specify it as a template parameter which then gets instantiated and called in the function. I think this way is slightly cleaner.

Comment: +1 Nice suggestions. I know to some people this feels like overkill, but to me it feels elegant (no duplicated code = no finding errors twice...)